# Django template get value from foreign keys without context

Tags: html, django

I have the following data model:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    membership_type = models.CharField(choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES, default='Free', max_length=11)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    stripe_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type


class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

In my **nav bar** I would like to show the **membership_type** if the user is authenticated. Is it possible to do it without a view passing the context?

I tried the following:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ request.user.usermembership.membership.membership_type }}
    {{ request.user.usermembership_set.membership_set.membership_type }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here a user can have zero, one, or more `Membership`s, since you made a `ForeignKey` to the user model, not a `OneToOneField`. You thus can iterate over the `UserMembership` objects, and render the `.membership_type` of the related `.membership` for each item:

```
{% for usermembership in request.user.usermembership_set.all %}
    {{ usermembership.membership.membership_type }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you make this a `OneToOneField`:

```
class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneFied(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

we can render this with:

```
{{ request.user.usermembership.membership.membership_type }}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. If I want to change the ForeignKey to a OneToOneField can I still use this solution?

Comment: You can also use `related_name` attribute `user = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name='memberships')` to name the relation as `user.memberships`

Comment: @S.A: no, then it is `{{ request.user.usermembership.membership.membership_type }}`. Note that a `OneToOne` means a `User` can only have *one* `UserMembership`, so the modeling then changes.

Comment: Yes this is the case. I will change it and use the solution in your comment. Could you please update your answer (but keep the first solution)